# Malware protection gone awry?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

I tried to leave this comment on a question about SQL injection (but with straight quotes instead of curly ones) and got the big red error box.

> Get rid of the last `'` so your password looks like this: 'foo' or '1'='1'

Looking at the transaction in the browser inspector, I got no response at all. A packet trace in Wireshark showed the server sending nothing but a TCP RST packet in response to my POST. Is this maybe some kind of malware protection on the web server?

It wouldn't let me submit the comment until I added some space around the `=` at the end:

> Get rid of the last `'` so your password looks like this: 'foo' or '1' = '1'

Edit: I couldn't submit this question without making those changes to the quotes either!

Comment: Get rid of the last `'` so your password looks like this: `foo' or '1'='1`

Comment: Well, I didn't have any trouble submitting the comment or question. Are you sure you're not mixing up *backticks* and *straight quotes*?

Comment: Certainly not. I've left a few thousand comments, I know how it works ;) Just tried editing my question and am unable to with your changes. At least I have a packet trace to prove I'm not crazy.

Comment: That is very odd. I cannot imagine that the system would treat a 10k+ user any different here than a 100k+ user.

Comment: Agreed; this seems like it is at the web server level, not anything that should be able to differentiate between users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely your local network. Apparently there are firewalls which make a habit of blocking outbound requests that they think are malicious in some way. I've found nothing in *our* logs to suggest you're being blocked, and your symptoms match previous reports of this problem from others.

For a longer discussion of this problem, see: [Asking an SQL Question Appears to Cause Internet Connection Loss](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340068/asking-an-sql-question-appears-to-cause-internet-connection-loss)

Comment: Interesting. Just a standard Asus router here, but I'm in university housing so might be something upstream. Definitely makes sense.